# Difference between "mortals" and "the mortals" in a text where "the" doesn't seem to be referring to specific ones

Tags: articles, definite-article

Here is a tale from a video game. Sheogorath is a god, a so-called Daedric Prince, *whose sphere is Madness, and whose motives are unknowable*.

> In the earliest of days, in a time when the world was still raw, Sheogorath decided to walk amongst **the mortals**. He donned his guise of Gentleman With a Cane, and moved from place to place without being recognized. After eleven days and eleven nights, Sheogorath decided that life among **mortals** was even more boring than his otherworldly existence.
>
> "What can I do to make their lives more interesting?" he said to himself. At that same moment, a young woman nearby commented wistfully to herself, "The sounds of the birds are so beautiful."
>
> Sheogorath silently agreed with her. **Mortals** could not make the beautiful and inspired calls of birds. Their voices were wretched and mundane. He could not change the nature of **mortals**, for that was the purview of other Daedric Princes. However, he could give them tools to make beautiful sounds.
>
> Sheogorath took hold of the petulant woman and ripped her asunder. From her tendons he made lutes. From her skull and arm bones he made a drum. From her bones he made flutes. He presented these gifts to **the mortals**, and thus Music was born.

I don't see why *the* is being used in those two sentences. The definite article doesn't seem to be describing any specific mortals.

There was [an answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/78697/21520) about half a month ago:

> > I was in the N.Y. Library. I was reading **the books** there, and one book interested me.
>
> This sentence treats "the books" as a single fixture in the New York Library. That doesn't make sense if you're reading them; it makes sense in a context like this:
>
> > **The** yearly cost to insure **the books** in the New York Library is over a million dollars.

As in the above example, is the article in my text referring to all mortals as a single entity (i.e. not individually)?

Comment: It's really just an *optional* stylistic choice in your case. Semantically equivalent, apart from the *last* one - which would be a bit "odd" without the article (I think it would tend to imply *presented these gifts to **certain unspecified individual** mortals*). But consider [*Julian Assange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_Assange) does not trust **the** Americans.* With the article, it (correctly) means he doesn't trust Americans *collectively* (as represented by the US govt). Without, it would (wrongly) mean he doesn't trust *any **individual** who happens to be an American.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal usage, and your hunch is correct: this has nothing to do with describing any "specific" mortals. This is a case where English uses "the" to reference a group of people or a species in a generalized sense. For example:

> *I like walking alone in the woods so that I can listen to **the** birds*.
>
> *There he [Biddle] lived with **the** natives, learned their language, and worked at his painting*.
>
> *Through characters like Tom Bombadil and **the** Ents, Tolkien seems to be saying that nature is an entity separate from ourselves.* (Anne Pienciak)
>
> *You have made him a little lower than **the** angels, and crowned him with glory and honor*. (Ps. 8)

---

Some additional information about  varied uses of *the* can be found at [this related ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22647/uses-of-the-definite-article-the-in-generic-noun-phrases/22650#22650).

Answer (score 1):

The 'the' refers to all mortals as a single entity.

Note that when you omit the 'the', you are usually referring to mortals as a class, you are signaling to the reader that you are about to describe or define that class.

like below...

**"Mortals could not make the beautiful and inspired calls of birds."**

Answer (score 0):

A way to explain the use of **the** is to ask what the choice of determiner means *to the person whose thoughts the words reveal*, whoever that may be.

In normal conversation, people speak for themselves. In a story, sometimes the narrator is revealing his or her own thoughts but sometimes the thoughts of the character whose story is being told.

The choice of a definite article here implies that someone, either the narrator or Sheogorath, **has in mind** *members of a particular class*, just as we might if we were to say

> The king decided to walk among *the* commoners.