# "Tip often climbed trees for birds' eggs or amused himself chasing the fleet white rabbits or fishing in the brooks" -- why the definite articles?

Tags: articles, definite-article, determiners

Here is a sentence from *The Marvelous Land of Oz*:

> When sent to the forest Tip often climbed **trees** for **birds'** eggs or amused himself chasing **the fleet white rabbits** or fishing in **the brooks** with bent pins.

All the things in bold haven't been mentioned before. Why is it *birds* but *the rabbits* and *trees* but *the brooks* if all these things are in the same forest?

I think [the following piece](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/78697/21520) would be relevant:

> > At Canter's Deli, you should get **the** corned-beef sandwich.
>
> Here, "the" is appropriate because bringing up the deli implicitly brings up typical items on the menu.
>
> > I was in the N.Y. Library. I was reading **the books** there, and one book interested me.
>
> "Oh, you were reading the *books*!" As opposed to what, the posters on the wall? Usually when there is grammatical ambiguity, a listener will use common sense to avoid making an absurd interpretation, but in this case, the absurdity is hard to avoid because a listener understands this sentence by analogy with the "…and fixed the sink" and "…get the corned-beef sandwich" sentences.

I don't know if I understand that answer completely. Did the author omit the article because it was obvious that every forest had trees and birds? Did he use the article to point out that in some forests there might not be white rabbits or brooks, but in his forest they were there and were some of its features?

Comment: The rabbits and the brooks are the ones found *there* in Oz. Compare: "What I like best about that amusement park is *the* ferris wheel." The definite article has a meaning there quite close to the possessive "its".

Comment: Do you like this jacket?  --I like *the* color, but I don't care for *the* wide lapels.

Comment: @TRomano In other words, there's a kind of rabbits and brooks unique to Oz (that's why they use the article) while the trees and birds there aren't different from those we have in our world (that's why they don't). Is that what you mean?

Comment: There's not necessarily any implication of absolute uniqueness, but these are features peculiar to, or characteristic of, Oz.  If the birds eggs were unusual in some Oz-like way, an author might write "climbed trees to fetch *the* birds eggs with their polka-dot shells".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### About the absence of article before trees and birds'

In **Tip often climbed trees for birds' eggs**: it is not that it's obvious that every forest has trees and birds, but more that they are not special trees or birds.

The character just used to climb **some** trees to find **some** birds's eggs. The presence of *often* emphasizes the fact that it was a routine and that there was nothing important about these trees and eggs. We thus have no reason to point at them with a definite article.

### About the rabbits

The presence of the article *the* is justified by the explicit description of the rabbits. These were not just **random** rabbits, but rather the **fleet white** ones. The author could have said:

> or amused himself chasing rabbits or fishing

Because they are just random rabbits and the center of attention is on the action itself, **chasing**. But for whatever reason, he decided to give some importance to the rabbits, hence the presence of an adjective and the article "the".

### About the brooks

Again, the author felt like emphasizing on **the brooks**, and not just any random brooks.

### In short

Every choice of article conveys an intention from the author. If he wants to describe random objects among plenty others, he would use **a/an/nothing**. If he wants to explicitly point at them, he will use **the**. 
Every time you use **the** instead of **a/an/nothing**, the center of attention shifts from the verb to the object you're describing.